# Cannot open StackOverflow in Mozilla Firefox. Potential Security Issue. Certificate Validation Issue

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, security, browser

I am having problem in opening stackoverflow.com in Mozilla Firefox. However It is working in Google Chrome

**I am getting error:**

> #### Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue.
>
> Firefox detected an issue and did not continue to stackoverflow.com. The website is either misconfigured or your computer clock is set to the wrong time.
> It’s likely the website’s certificate is expired, which prevents Firefox from connecting securely.
> **What can you do about it?**
> stackoverflow.com has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.
> The issue is most likely with the website, and there is nothing you can do to resolve it. You can notify the website’s administrator about the problem.

**Here is the Screenshot:**
[image]

I have Checked the Certificate in Firefox, it is displaying as expired on Firefox, but in Chrome it is not showing as expired.

**In Firefox:**

[image]

**In Chrome:**

[image]

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have different rules to determine when to display that a website using an invalid certificate. @user1686 - removed my last comment.  Could not find the meta announcement stating that fact

Comment: So what can I do? I am not able to open Stack Overflow in Firefox.

Comment: The first thing I would do is try a brand new Firefox user profile. Be sure you backup the current profile.

Comment: The serial number for the certificate is `03:09:59:5F:7B:68:8D:AF:2C:A4:8C:52:5C:74:CA:17:E1:72`, so if that isn't matching what Firefox is presenting, then it might be a cache issue.